# Hybris Sitemap doesn't contain all products

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, xml-sitemap

I'm having a problem with sitemap generation in Hybris, after successfully finished generation Job, site map doesn't contain all products that must be there.Problem is not related with products.Products url which are not contained in sitemap can be successfully there if I run this job only for them.Problem likely with product count and SiteMapUrlLimitPerFile attribute.If this value set by default(50 000 urls per file) in whole site map I have 5000 url , but if I'll change this value to 10 000 url per file in summary I have more then 10 000 products url.In OOTB logic ,list with all products is spited in Lists by SiteMapUrlLimitPerFile attribute(every list represents file).I checked OOTB logic , it correctly splits products in lists, but seems to be that not all products from lists are written to file.
Is anyone faced similar problem?
PS:I use Hybris 6.6.0.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found out the answer for my own question, maybe it will be useful for someone in future.

I have VM template that handles list with products, loops through list and print URL of each entry. Problem was in maximum allowed number of times that a loop may be executed in VM templates. That value is set in property `directive.foreach.maxloops`.In my case every template handles a list with 50 000 products but maximum allowed number of times that a loop may be executed is 1024.
For more details please take a look  http://people.apache.org/~henning/velocity/html/ch05s04.html#d0e1269

Comment: Thanks for your share. It helped a lot. Alone the name of the property was changed. Now it is called directive.foreach.max_loops

Comment: @AleaM I'm very glad to hear it helped someone :)